# PHP - Need to remove duplicate characters within a String but would like to include exceptions

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, duplicates

I have been searching all over the internet for a solution, but could not find one.

I need to remove duplicate characters within a String but would also like to include an exception to allow a integer amount of characters to repeat / remain in the string.

**For example, I tried the following:**

```
$str = 'This ----------is******** a bbbb 999-999-9999 ******** 8888888888 test 4444444444 ********##########Sammy!!!!!! ###### hello !!!!!!';

$t1 = preg_replace('/(.)\1{3,}/','',$str);
$t2 = preg_replace('/(\S)\1{3,}/','',$str);
$t3 = preg_replace('{(.)\1+}','$1',$str);
$t4 = preg_replace("/[;,:\s]+/",',',$str);
$t5 = preg_replace('/\W/', '', $str);
$t6 = preg_replace( "/[^a-z]/i", "", $str);

echo '$t1 = '.$t1.'<br>';
echo '$t2 = '.$t2.'<br>';
echo '$t3 = '.$t3.'<br>';
echo '$t4 = '.$t4.'<br>';
echo '$t5 = '.$t5.'<br>';
echo '$t6 = '.$t6.'<br>';
```

**Results:**

```
$t1 = This is a 999-999- test Sammy hello 
$t2 = This is a 999-999- test Sammy hello 
$t3 = This -is* a b 9-9-9 * 8 test 4 *#Samy! # helo !
$t4 = This,----------is********,a,bbbb,999-999-9999,********,8888888888,test,4444444444,********##########Sammy!!!!!!,######,hello,!!!!!!
$t5 = Thisisabbbb99999999998888888888test4444444444Sammyhello
$t6 = ThisisabbbbtestSammyhello
```

**The desired out put would be:**

```
This ---is*** a bbbb 999-999-9999 *** 8888888888 test 4444444444 ***###Sammy!!! ### hello !!!
```

As you can see, the **desired** output leaves the numbers alone and only leaves 3 repeated characters, i.e. --- ### *** !!!

I would like to be able to change the exceptions from 3 to any other integer if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/([^0-9])\1{3,}`? if you want to allow digits to repeat, then exclude digits from the repetition check.

Comment: thanks, but how would the entire preg_replace statement be written to incorporate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
preg_replace('/(([^\d])\2\2)\2+/', '$1', $str);
```

`[^\d]` matches a single character which isn't a digit.
`\2` refers to the captured digit
`$1` refers to the first captured group which will be the first three repeated characters, so the extra `\2+` gets stripped off.

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/d3Qyd4)

Comment: If I wanted to retain 4 repeated characters, would I change all the 2's to 3's and so on? I tried using 3,'s but that did not work.

Comment: @Sammy No, `\2` refers to the digit captured by the second set of parentheses (the character that matched `[^\d]`. To retain 4 characters you would change `\2\2` to `\2\2\2`. That will keep one extra character, once you're at that many though it's better to change it to `\2{3}` which is a shorthand for `\2` three times. IE. `\2{5}` is shorthand for `\2\2\2\2\2`

Comment: Hm, this doesn't work. I use different regex which does the trick: preg_replace('{([^\w])\1+}','',$str);

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for: `/((.)\2{2})\2*/`
If you need exception `n`, put `n-1` in the curly brace `{n-1}`: `/((.)\2{n-1})\2*/`

EDIT: for non-number or what ever you what, replace `.` with other things, for example `[^\d]` etc. `/(([^\d])\2{2})\2*/`

Comment: I forgot to add that you have to capture `$1`