# How can I detect repeating characters in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Need to remove duplicate characters within a String but would like to include exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761403/php-need-to-remove-duplicate-characters-within-a-string-but-would-like-to-incl)

I have a string of text below in php.

```
$string = "@@@@@@ CHECK ME OUT! @@@@@@@@";
```

or

```
$string = "//////// CHECK ME OUT! ////////";
```

The will pretty much will use any character word or key to stand out from the rest when they post. My question is, is there a function or something I can use to prevent people from spamming a key or character.

So if what ever character or key is used more then three times it will remove it. So it will look like this below.

```
$string = "CHECK ME OUT!";
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a bad approach - do you require a log in to post? use a CAPTCHA?

Comment: This would be difficult, because what's to say the script takes out the double-f in the world 'difficult'?

Comment: and in some languages there are words with 3+ consecutive letters

Comment: @david that's why I said after three :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11634313/102937

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use a [regular expression to match a repeated character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times):

```
$string = "//////// CHECK ME OUT! ////////";
echo preg_replace('/(.)\1{3,}/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a charlist in [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

```
$string = "//////// CHECK ME OUT! ////////";
echo trim($string, "/\$@");
```

This will trim (from front and end of string) any character in the list. No strings should being or end with `/\%@` so that should be a pretty safe thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/(.)\1\1+/', '', $string);
```